# Annoying border around gif if I define size

Tags: javascript

So I'm just learning basic javascript at the moment and I decided to learn how to make an image/gif appear with the press of the button. I did the whole button script and when the image appeared I thought it was too large. I decided to add some height and width attributes to my img tag and now when I refresh the page a border appears around where the gif will appear. I really don't want this and also want to understand why this happens. Thank you!

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('secretImage').src='wahoo.gif'">Ok</button>

<br>

<img id="secretImage" width="150px" height="150px"/>
```

I now realize that you guys won't be able to see the image I saved, but I don't think it will affect your understanding of my problem. If I am wrong about this, please tell me.

Comment: First of all, `width` and `height` attributes don't require units (unlike css properties). What browser? What's `whaoo.gif`?

Comment: Is the result any different if you use css styles instead of width and height attributes?  Css styles are generally regarded as a better practice anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO, and thank you for providing the needed information.

The problem that you are experiencing is on page load, the image URL isn't applied so the browser is showing you a missing photo icon, that you have set to 150px square.

There are many solutions for this, but as you are a beginner, I will offer up the simplest solution.

You can simply hide the img tag by default, then make it visible on click.

```js
    function show_image(){
       var _img = document.getElementById('secretImage');
       _img.style.display = "block";
       _img.src='https://via.placeholder.com/150';
    }
```

```html
    <button type="button" onclick="show_image()">Ok</button>
    
    <br>
    
    <img style="display:none;" id="secretImage" width="150" height="150"/>
```